# Powrshell to export list of all PCs and if they have specific application install

Tags: powershell

I currently use the following powershell script to export the list of all VMs on our network with their information and export into an excel file:

```bsh
    #// Set CSV file name 
    $uDateTime = Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM" 
    $uCSVFile = "C:\Servers"+$uDateTime+".csv" 

    #//Export out to csv file.
    Get-ADComputer -filter * -Properties ipv4Address, OperatingSystem,DistinguishedName | 
    select-object Name, ipv4Address, OperatingSystem,  @{label='OU';expression= 
    {$_.DistinguishedName.Split(',')[1].Split('=')[1]}} |
    export-csv -path $uCSVFile
```

The excel content would look something like this:

[image]

I want to add another column to indicate if specific application exists on each server or not like this one

[image]

Upon googling around I see that I can utilize the Get-ItemProperty to read the registry in order to check if certain program is installed on individual VM, but I am having problem tying the code to my existing one.  It gives me the same result based on the machine where this PowerShell scripts runs on instead of each VM registry individually ...

Can you help me making this script read each VM's registry

```bsh
    #// Set CSV file name 
    $uDateTime = Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM" 
    $uCSVFile = "C:\Servers"+$uDateTime+".csv" 

    #//Export out to csv file.
    Get-ADComputer -filter * -Properties ipv4Address, OperatingSystem,DistinguishedName | 
    select-object Name, ipv4Address, OperatingSystem,  @{label='OU';expression= 
    {$_.DistinguishedName.Split(',')[1].Split('=')[1]}},
    @{label='HelloKitty Installed';expression={(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\HelloKitty\*" | Where { 
    $_.Version -ne $null }) -ne $null}}|
    export-csv -path $uCSVFile
```

Comment: You're picking out info from the AD computer object. Does the registry data actually exist in each AD object? You are likely going to need to invoke the command against the remote computers to get that info.

Comment: Your code is not reading imported CSV data inside a Microsoft Excel. A CSV does not have rows or columns, it has records and fields. If you need assistance, you should delete those screenshots, and post the respective raw CSV content, formatted exactly as required for willing assistants to copy, and reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a registry key from the computer you are targetting instead of the computer the script is currently running from, you should use the [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) cmdlet.
However, keep in mind that `Get-ADComputer` can also list computers that are currently off-line, so I would suggest using a ForEach-Object loop which will give you a chance to test for that first.

Something like this:

```
#// Set CSV file name 
$uCSVFile = 'C:\Servers{0:yyyy-MM}.csv' -f (Get-Date)

#//Export out to csv file.
$result = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties ipv4Address, OperatingSystem,DistinguishedName | 
ForEach-Object {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        # computer is on line. If need be, add -Credential to the Invoke-Command cmdlet
        # because reading the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE hive needs Administrator permissions.
        # Also, the targetted machines must have the 'Remote Registry' service enabled.
        try {
            $installed = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.Name -ScriptBlock {
                            $null -ne (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\HelloKitty\*" | 
                                       Where-Object { $null -ne $_.Version }).Version
                         } -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch { $installed = "ERROR" }
    }
    else { $installed = "OFF-LINE" }

    # output an object
    $_ | Select-Object Name, ipv4Address, OperatingSystem,
                       @{Name = 'HelloKitty Installed'; Expression = { $installed }}
}

# now export to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path $uCSVFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>I have added switch `-UseCulture` to the Export-Csv cmdlet so the delimiter character used in the csv file will be the same as your local Excel expects</sup>

Comment: This is what I am looking for.  That ForEach-Object and Invoke-Command is what I did not know.  Thank you Theo.